# How to enable "Click-to-play" in Google Chrome Version 43.0.2357.124 (64-bit)?

Tags: google-chrome, power-management, plugins

I run Google Chrome Version 43.0.2357.124 (64-bit) on OS X Yosemite.

I want to enable **Click to play** option, mainly because I would like to lower the power usage of Google Chrome and Google Chrome Helper processes.

However, I cannot find it under **Settings** > **Content settings** > **Plugins** and it should be there according to [Why does Google Chrome Helper spike my CPU?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/138616/why-does-google-chrome-helper-spike-my-cpu) and many other webpages.

**Question:**

Has Google decided to removed this particular **Click to play** feature from Chrome or for e.g. it has moved to some other section of the Settings?

One way or another, is it possible to enable **Click to play** option for plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Google Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit) on macOS Sierra 10.12.2

It looks like the solution for Chrome 43 doesn't work any longer as the **Let me choose choose when to run plugin content** option is no longer present in the settings.

At the moment you can:

1. Open **Settings** (you can do it by clicking **[image: More]** and then **Settings** or by clicking <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>).
2. Click **+ Show advanced settings**.
3. Enter the **Content settings** in the *Privacy* section.
4. Go to the *Flash* section and choose **Block sites from running Flash**.

More information here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142064?hl=en

---

#### Google Chrome Version 43.0.2357.124 (64-bit) on OS X Yosemite

Ok, so I've found it. It is not presented as **Click to play** any longer (it used to be in previous versions of Chrome and is still presented like this in Chromium).

If you want to turn this option on you've got to:

1. Open **Settings** (you can do it by clicking **☰** and then **Settings** or by clicking <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>).
2. Click **Show advanced settings...**.
3. Enter the **Content settings** in the **Privacy** section.
4. Enable **Let me choose choose when to run plugin content** in the **Plugins** section.

[image]

It seems quite obvious now, but I've been trying to find this for a few weeks by now, because it was called **Click to play** before.

Comment: Thanks for tracking this down.  It looks as though when `Click to Play` was replaced my setting defaulted back to `Detect & run important plugin content`.  Under this setting though, I haven't experienced the awful spikes I used to have.  FWIW.

Comment: I don't have this Plugins section. Chrome version  55.0.2883.95 on OS X.

Comment: @shrx I updated the answer. However, I'm a little bit confused now whether it still works the way it used to.